# Power efficient and Speed efficient architecture for Multimedia Applications

Tags: architecture, processor, multimedia, vliw

I am working on evaluating a embedded processor architecture which offers below features:

- 8 SIMD co-processing DSP kind of cores,
- Each core can do a 8 way SIMD
- Each core is a 8 execution slot VLIW as well.

I want to use high video encoder(H.264, 1080p, 60fps) or 3D Video encoder to run on this processor/hardware. I am trying to perform architectural exploration and find

- What are the good featrues of a processor should have which help in carrying out  multimedia(Video/Image) Signal processing applications in power/cycle/memory efficient way.
- What peripherals,memory structure, either cache memory or internal memory;additional  assembly instructions help in efficient execution of code for multimedia applications
- What are most power efficient and fast processor architectures for Multimedia(Video/Image) processing applications

PS: It has to be low power as it is for portable applications.

Any pointers(papers/blogs) would be helpful.

thank you.

-AD.

Comment: what a cores do you talk about? It is a processor with 8-way SIMD or it is a processor with a dsp coprocessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that "most power efficient and fast processor architectures for Multimedia(Video/Image) processing" is a special hardware cores to do a specific video/image encoding operation. E.g. the fastest mpeg4 avc encoder will be a hardware encoder, isnt it?

For example, there is scheme of VP9 hardware decoder: http://www.webmproject.org/hardware/vp9/
[image: Scheme of Google's VP9 hardware decoder]

It even has no any big CPU/MCU.
The encoder is more complex and less public thing... But there is some project: http://hardh264.sourceforge.net/H264-encoder-manual.html with scheme:

[image: Zexia video H.264 Hardware Encoder scheme]

or VP8 encoder from google: http://www.webmproject.org/hardware/vp8/

[image: WebM Video Encoder Hardware IP from google - scheme]

Again, no big CPU. And you can check what stages was separated by designer, and think about how you will implement them in CPU: DCT, quantisation, prediction, entrophy coding, YUV/RBG conversion, etc